# Insert information from view into another table without user input

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a web service, with `C#` and `Visual Studio 2010`, that will insert values form a view table into another table using a `SQL` query. In the past we have used this type of service but we have asked the user to enter the values they want to update, but with the query I am using there is no need for user input since the values will be inserted only when one of the field values is `NULL`.

Below is the code I been trying to use, I adapted the code we used before, but in here I am still expecting user input. How can I update my code as to not expect the input. I know I can just run this query from `MySQL` but I want be able to create a button in our site so other people can do it. Here is the code that runs the query:

```
public void AddUsers(string json)
{
    GetDbInstance();

    var sql = "insert into dbo.ASPECTS_users_activity " +
              "(user_id, usr_address, usr_phone, usr_email, usr_website, usr_photo ) " +
              "select @v.customer_id, @usr_address, @usr_phone, @usr_email, @usr_website, @usr_photo  " +
              "from dbo.ASPECTS_current_users_vw v where usr_photo is NULL;";

    var usrInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateExhibitors>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(usrInformation);

    var conn = db.Connection();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v.customer_id", usrInformation.master_customer_id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_address", "123 XYZ Post, Columbus, IN");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_phone", "555-555-5555");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_email", "test@sample.com");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_website", "http://www.sample.com");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_photo", "");

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.Dispose();

        command = null;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.ToString(), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Customer_Insert.Models {
    public class AddUsers {
        public string customer_id { get; set; }
        public string usr_address { get; set; }
        public string usr_phone { get; set; }
        public string usr_email { get; set; }
        public string usr_website { get; set; }
        public string usr_photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Just so you know the only field that will be populated from the view to will be the `customer_id` field, all the other fields will have default values, which will be updated at another point. Not many people here know `SQL` so creating this option will provide an option if I am not around.

Comment: Try removing the `@` character at the start of the view column: `select v.customer_id, ...`

Comment: @RichardDeeming, thanks for the input but what I am trying to find is how to change my code to not require user input, pretty much to do out with out having `string json`

Comment: The only place you're using the parameter is to get the value for the `@v.customer_id` parameter. As that value is supposed to be coming from the view, if you remove the `@` sign in the query, you can remove the query parameter, which means you can remove the `usrInformation` variable, which means you can remove the `json` method parameter.

Comment: So I would only need to keep the `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);` and anything below `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` in the `try` block, there is no need for `command.Parameters.AddWithValue`? I am lost on how I will rewrite it, Thanks

Comment: You'd get rid of the *first* `AddWithValue`, which relies on the `json` parameter. All of the other `AddWithValue` calls are using static values, so you can leave them as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you "can just run this query from MySQL", I would save that query as a Stored Procedure in your database.  Then you need neither SQL nor parameters in your code.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("yourStoredProcedureName", conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Sgr3005, that did the trick, I wasn't able to test it until today but it works.